# Manipulating preseed options during debian-installer

Tags: linux, shell-script, preseed

Currently I am trying to build a more or less dynamic preseed. This means I am creating custom templates/question and depending on the answers I want to set specific "d-i" options. My environment is ubuntu/debian using the debian-installer.

These are executed using the following command: 
`d-i preseed/early_command string wget -qO preseed_early_command.sh http://myurl/preseed/server/bionic/preseed_early_command.sh && sh preseed_early_command.sh`

Depending on the language selection I am trying to set specific options using `debconf-set` and it looks like they are recognized but I am still getting language dialog after `early_command` finishes (tho all set values are set correctly following the questions asked)

```
if [ "$(debconf-get language-select/select)" = "German" ]; then
    debconf-set debian-installer/language "de"
    debconf-set debian-installer/country "DE"
    debconf-set debian-installer/locale "de_DE.UTF-8"
    debconf-set console-setup/ask_detect false
    debconf-set keyboard-configuration/layoutcode "de"
    debconf-set keyboard-configuration/variantcode "nodeadkeys"
fi
```

**How can I prevent the installer asking me the questions again despite being set? Is it even possible to manipulate the preseed in such a way I am trying to?**

Depending on the machine type selection (i.e. Desktop / Headless) I would want to set the tasksel/pkgsel options. But these always fail with an error whether I am trying to run them directly or using `debconf-set`

```
if [ "$(debconf-get machine-type/select)" = "Ubuntu Desktop" ]; then
    debconf-set tasksel/first multiselect ubuntu-desktop
    debconf-set pkgsel/include openssh-server build-essential nano vim hardinfo htop remmina bash-completion dkms dialog
elif [ "$(debconf-get machine-type/select)" = "Ubuntu Headless" ]; then
    debconf-set tasksel/first multiselect standard
    debconf-set pkgsel/include "openssh-server nano vim htop bash-completion ntp"
fi
```

**How are the "pkgsel/tasksel" options being executed/evaluated? Tasksel doesn't seem to be availabe at this stage as busybox throws `not found`.**

Comment: While both topics are loosely related, there are two separate questions asked here. Could the second question please be moved into a separate post? As stated in in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/), asking multiple questions at once is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

This answer only attempts to cover the first of the two questions asked.

Within the debian-installer `debconf-set` is a short shellscript, which merely source [confmodule(3)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/debconf-doc/confmodule.3.en.html) and calls `db_set $1 $2`. The more useful command is `debconf-set-selections` which, as can by understood from [debconf-set-selections(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/debconf/debconf-set-selections.1.en.html), takes a file in the same format as a preseed file as its argument. Supposedly it should also accept data on stdin, but I was unsuccessful getting that to work in the debian-installer environment.

e.g.:

```
VALUES=`mktemp`
cat > "${VALUES}" << END_OF_DEBCONF
d-i time/zone string Antarctica/Troll
END_OF_DEBCONF
debconf-get-selections "${VALUES}"
```

Also. It might be simpler merely using `preseed/run` with a script, than reconstructing the same functionality by using `preseed/early_command`.